# How do you get a random number from a non-consecutive set?

Tags: python, random

I need to randomly select from the numbers `[1, 4, 7, 9, 13, 42]`.

I can't use `random.randint(1,42)` because it would give me some of the numbers in-between. How do I select from only those numbers in my list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want `random.choice`.

```
import random
random.choice([1,4,7,9,13,42])
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out too!

Comment: No problem.  It's always nice to see someone continue their research and find the answer to their own question :)

Answer (score 3):

I did some more research and found that I can use `random.choice([1, 4, 7, 9, 13, 42])`, which will randomly pick an item from the list.